# Relation between covariance and bandwidth in gaussian_kde

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to implement a 2D parzen window on a cluster of data to estimate the PDF. I'm doing this for school and one of the requirements is to use a Gaussian window with covariance `σ^2=400`.

I decided to use the `gaussian_kde` class provided by SciPy.stats. However, I'm not sure what value of bandwidth to provide. I see documentation about Scott's rule and Silverman's rule but I was wondering how to incorporate the `σ^2=400` requirement into this parameter.

In other words, what is the relationship between the covariance of the Gaussian parzen window and the bandwidth parameter of the `gaussian_kde` class?

Comment: It's not clear from the documentation, but I *think* from reading the source code here https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/stats/kde.py#L210-L264 that it's not possible to directly specify the covariance matrix for the kernel using `gaussian_kde`. Instead you are only able to specify a factor by which it multiplies the covariance of the data itself to produce the bandwidth. It shouldn't be too hard to roll your own since you already know what the kernel is.